# How to fix the sorting issue that occurs during sales or purchase orders posting?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, ax

We are facing the following sorting issue during invoice posting in Dynamics AX 2009. Application version is given below.

Dynamics AX 2009 with Service Pack 1 and **Roll Up 5** installed.
Version: **5.0.1500.2985** (Both Kernel and Application)

Following are the steps that our users are performing:

1. Navigated to `Accounts receivable --> Periodic --> Sales update --> Invoice`
2. On the `Posting invoice` form, clicked on the select button.
3. On the `Sales update` dialog, clicked on the Sorting tab.
4. Changed the search direction of field `Sales order` to **Descending**.
5. Deleted the `Order lines - Line No - Ascending` row from sorting.
6. Clicked **Ok** to exit Sales update dialog.

After the data is retrieved, I see the Sales orders listed in the Posting invoice form's **Overview** tab in ascending order.

We don't have any sorting parameters set up in `Accounts receivable --> Setup --> Forms --> Form sorting --> Invoice.` So, I don't think that is the problem.

I was also able to simulate this scenario in the standard code that didn't have any customizations.

I would like to know if anyone has a solution to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

**`UPDATE:`**

I just found out from Microsoft Support that the `Posting Invoice` form is working as per design. So, I have to make a change in order for the form to function the way our users would like it to work. If I can find a solution, I will post it here.

To add more to the question, same thing happens in the Purchase Order Posting form as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally users can change the sorting whenever needed by simply clicking the `Sales order` header in the grid, however if the default sorting needs to be changed the following can be done.

Open method `\Forms\SalesEditLines\Methods\init`.
After the following line:

```
salesParmTable_ds.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(SalesParmTable)).addRange(fieldnum(SalesParmTable, ParmId)).value(queryValue(parmId));
```

add a new one:

```
salesParmTable_ds.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(SalesParmTable)).addSortField(fieldnum(SalesParmTable, SalesId), SortOrder::Descending);
```

NB: the default sorting will be changed for all processes that use this form e.g. Picking list, Delivery note, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard the order of the records in the "Posting invoice" form - the invoices will be posted in the order specified by your sorting parameters, that is the Sales order with the greatest sales order number will be invoiced first.

Comment: Hmm, I tested it and the invoices were printed in the reverse order. Anyway, if the purpose is to change the default sorting in the form please check my new answer.